# How can I move a file to another folder, but only if it hasn't been modified since 10 minutes?

Tags: scripting, cron, move

Replace the "10 minutes" with whatever value. Basically I only want to move the file if it's not growing any more. How can I do this on the command-line or a bash script?

A solution that is easy to `cron` is preferred.

---

Details:

- OS: CentOS
- What I have tried so far: nothing because I don't know where to even start
- What kind of files: any files in a directory

Comment: On what operating system? What have you tried so far? Which part of this is giving you trouble? Is this for one specific file? Will you know the file name? Will you need to find all files that haven't been modified in the last N minutes? Please [edit] your question and give us some context so we can understand better.

Comment: @terdon Thanks. I modified my post as honestly as I could.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example? Will there always be a specific directory? Do you just want to find all files that have not been modified in the last N minutes in `/some/path` and move them to `/some/other/path`? Have you looked at `man find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line command here:

```
find /path/to/dir1 -type f ! -mmin -10 -exec mv {} /path/to/dir2 \;
```

Replace `-10` with whatever you want, the rule is:

```
+n     for greater than n,
-n     for less than n,
n      for exactly n.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

Using find:

```
if find some_directory -mmin +10 | grep "^filename$" ; then
    mv filename somewhere_else
fi
```

Another way would be to calculate the md5sum and compare that

```
touch .filename.md5

prev_md5=$(cat .filename.md5)
new_md5=$(md5sum filename)

if [ "$prev_md5" = "$new_md5" ] ; then
    mv filename somewhere_else
fi
echo "$new_md5" > .filename.md5
```

and run that every 10 minutes.

Comment: Why `grepping`? and not just print with `find` options?

Comment: Also possible.  The point was more to explore different options than to give a definitive solution Anyway, @linuxcmd.wiki has given you your find-options.

Comment: The problem is that if you use grep, you can move the wrong files. Not only because the file name might have a newline or a space, but more importantly because you are grepping for `filename` which means you will also find `thisotherfilename`.  At least make it `grep -x filename`. Oh, and you don't need to `touch` a file before writing to it.

Comment: Added the `^` and `$` to the grep. The touch is not before writing, but before the reading (`prev_md5=$(cat .filename.md5)`)